# Can my dryer exhaust crossing my HVAC duct be a fire hazard?

Tags: dryer

I have a dryer exhaust that crosses over a flexduct HVAC line, could the dryer vent cause a fire?

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt it since your dryer duct should never get hot enough.

With the said, a couple things to consider though 1) how close to the dryer does the HVAC line cross and 2) are they touching? If the HVAC tub is plastic covered, I would make sure that they are not touching as it might melt it.

You might also find this article useful: http://www.ashireporter.org/articles/articles.aspx?id=41